# jQuery for checkbox not work after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click on checkbox it's going to work but again when I am clicking on it, it's not working and checkboxSelected class is not going to remove.

Html markup:

```
 <div class="galleryMenu-center">
                <div class="galleryMenu-row" onclick="caruselFilter('.filter1984');">
                    <div class="checkbox"></div>
                    <div class="thisText">1984</div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
```

Html markup after click :

```
<div class="checkbox checkboxSelected" style="background-position: 0px -19px;"></div>
```

This is my jQuery code :

```
 $('.galleryMenu-row').click(function(){
        if($(this).find(".checkbox").hasClass('checkboxSelected')){
            $(this).find(".checkbox").removeClass('checkboxSelected');
            $(this).find(".checkbox").css('background-position', '0px -19px');
            var temcurrentShow = str_replace("," + currentClasa, "", currentShow);
            $(".imgSlideshow").css('display', 'block');
            //$(temcurrentShow).css('display', 'block');
        }
        $(this).find(".checkbox").addClass('checkboxSelected');
    });
```

best regards

Comment: `$(this).find(".checkbox").removeClass('checkboxSelected');` removes the class and `$(this).find(".checkbox").addClass('checkboxSelected');` adds it again. What do you expect? It seems you need an `else` block!

Comment: Why don't you actually use a checkbox? Simple CSS will allow you to have the images that you are using.

Comment: str_replace is no a javascript function. Use `var temcurrentShow = temcurrentShow.replace("," + currentClasa, "", currentShow);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you are adding always on click: `$(this).find(".checkbox").addClass('checkboxSelected');`

Maybe you want this?

```
if ($(this).find(".checkbox").hasClass('checkboxSelected')) {
    //...
} else {
    $(this).find(".checkbox").addClass('checkboxSelected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( this ).toggleClass( "checkboxSelected" );
```

Comment: `( "'checkboxSelected'" );` is wrong...remove one set of quotes.

Comment: Thanks epascarello...Well Spotted